# Affine transformation: rescaling alters the raster bounds?

Tags: python, scale, transform, rotate

I'm trying to rotate a raster around its center coordinates, rescaling the resolution by a factor. I expect the transformation to conserve the center pivot. However; it seems that after the rotation is performed, the program "zooms in" a section of the landscape, modifying the bounding box and the center coordinate, what is not what I expect.

Something is wrong with my use of the transform, but I cant' get what.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import numpy as np

def summary(dataset):
    print(" - no data value:", dataset.nodata )
    print(" - transform:\n")
    print(dataset.transform, "\n")
    print(" - ", dataset.bounds, "\n")
    pxsz, pysz = dataset.res
    print(" - pixel size X: \t", pxsz, "unit:", dataset.crs.linear_units)
    print(" - pixel size Y: \t", pysz, "unit:", dataset.crs.linear_units)
    return

def get_center_pixel(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    x_pixel_med = width // 2
    y_pixel_med = height // 2
    return (x_pixel_med, y_pixel_med)

def rotate_and_rescale(inputRaster, angle, scale=1, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.tif' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster

    ### Read input
    source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)
    assert source.crs == 'EPSG:4326', "Raster must have CRS=EPSG:4326, that is unprojected lon/lat (degree) relative to WGS84 datum"

    # Display information
    print("\nSource dataset:\n")
    summary(source)

    ### Rotate the affine about a pivot and rescale
    pivot = get_center_pixel(source)
    #pivot = None
    print("\nPivot coordinates:", source.transform * pivot)
    new_transform = source.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, pivot) * Affine.scale(scale)

    # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
    data = source.read(masked=True)
    kwargs = source.meta
    kwargs['transform'] = new_transform

    with rasterio.open(outputRaster, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, source.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(source, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=source.transform,
                src_crs=source.crs,
                dst_transform=new_transform,
                dst_crs=dst.crs,
                resampling=Resampling.average)

        # Display information
        print("\nNew rotated dataset:\n")
        summary(dst)

    return

def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="Rotated output raster name")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return rotate_and_rescale(args[0], float(args[1]), float(args[2]), options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what I was missing: the width and height of the destination also need to be rescaled by a factor (somehow I though reproject would handle that).

Also there was several issues around nodata handling, so I ended up casting everything from the source dtype to float, so I could use np.nan in the 3D arrays, then reproject from an array to the other, then replacing nans by the original source nodata value, and converting back to the original datatype. I think ideally I should make sure that casting can be done without loss of information, but I'm (almost) happy with the result I got.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import numpy as np

def get_center_pixel(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    x_pixel_med = width // 2
    y_pixel_med = height // 2
    return (x_pixel_med, y_pixel_med)

def rotate_and_rescale(inputRaster, angle, scale=1, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.tif' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster

    ### Read input
    with rasterio.open(inputRaster) as source:
        assert source.crs == 'EPSG:4326', "Raster must have CRS=EPSG:4326, that is unprojected lon/lat (degree) relative to WGS84 datum"

        ### Rotate the affine about a pivot and rescale
        pivot = get_center_pixel(source)
        print("\nPivot coordinates:", source.transform * pivot)

        # Apply transformation
        new_transform = source.transform*Affine.rotation(angle, pivot) * Affine.scale(scale)
        new_width = int(source.width // scale)
        new_height =  int(source.height // scale)

        # Update metadata
        kwargs = source.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({
            'count': source.count,
            'width': new_width,
            'height': new_height,
            'transform': new_transform,
            'nodata': source.nodata,
            'crs': source.crs
            })

        # Source data: use normal array because mask won't work with reproject
        src_data = source.read()
        source_type = src_data.dtype;
        src_data=src_data.astype('float64')
        src_data[src_data == source.nodata] = np.nan

        # Array to store destination data
        dst_shape=[source.count, new_height, new_width]
        dst_data = np.empty(dst_shape); dst_data[:] = np.nan

        with rasterio.open(outputRaster, mode='w', **kwargs) as dst:

            for i in range(1, source.count + 1):
                # Reproject from array to array
                reproject(
                    source=src_data[i-1],
                    destination=dst_data[i-1],
                    src_transform=source.transform,
                    src_crs=source.crs,
                    dst_transform=new_transform,
                    dst_crs=dst.crs,
                    resampling=Resampling.average,
                    dst_nodata=np.nan
                    )

            dst_data[np.isnan(dst_data)] = source.nodata
            dst_data=dst_data.astype(source_type)
            # Write to the output file
            dst.write(dst_data, indexes=range(1, source.count + 1))

    return

def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="Rotated output raster name")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return rotate_and_rescale(args[0], float(args[1]), float(args[2]), options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```